# wordpress script and content 404 network error absolute path error

Tags: css, wordpress, http-status-code-404, stylesheet

Configuration used: ubuntu server 14.04, php-fps, nginx, mysql 5.6 & latest wordpress. 
Under the webserver(nginx)
Configured the nginx absolute path as /var/www/html/wordpress/

but Under the wordpress directory:
the style sheets and image file types do not load(404 err) because they are looking for the path http://localhost/wordpress/wp-include & http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content .

As this wordpress directory is missing.
hence we had to create one more directory called "wordpress" and give the soft links to the wp-include & wp-content under this directory.

This being a temporary fix. where exactly do i need to make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should modify the site_url in the table in your database, where your site_url has been stored in the wp_option table. It might be `http://localhost/your-site/` change it to `http://localhost/wordpress/`

Hope this helps...